# PySpark Partitioning with Overlap

Tags: partitioning, overlap, pyspark

I am trying to partition my data to send to multiple machines for PySpark to run on at the same time, but then some of the data I want to send to one machine I also want to send to a different machine. How would I partition the data with overlaps?

Answer (score 0):

rdd.randomSplit([1]*N) returns a list of N equal sized rdd, I guess you can replicate items of your list before sending them